# Is it true that every connected graph (except $K1$) with no perfect matching $\textbf{must}$ have more than one maximum matching?

Tags: graph-theory

I have been trying to find a counterexample for such statement,
namely - a **unique maximum matching** (for a graph that is not K1 - 1 vertex, and has no perfect matching)
and cannot find one at all. Is it time to prove it formally, or does such a graph exist?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Words in capital letters usually mean shouting. You can make them bold.

Comment: how do I edit my question, and how do I make them bold?

Comment: It's easy: below the tag of your question, there would be the "edit" option (written in grey color). To make text bold, surround the text with two ** like this: `**bold text**`.

Comment: Should I edit the question?

Comment: well, I have done it but **text** just shows up as two asterisks on my end lol, maybe I've done something wrong

Comment: I forgot to mention that two asterisks work only for the body. In title, you have to use `$\textbf{bold text}$`. So I edited your question, but the title becomes longer than 150 characters, so it can't be done.

Comment: I fixed your title, and made it more readable as well.

Answer (score 3):

If the graph is not required to be connected the answer is no:
Consider a graph with 3 vertices and 1 edge, then clearly this graph has no perfect matching but its maximum matching (the matching containing the single edge) is unique.

However, for connected graphs the answer is yes:
Suppose we are given a graph $G$ which has no perfect matching and let $M$ be a maximum matching of $G$.
As $M$ is not perfect, there must exist some vertex $v$ not covered by $M$ which is connected to some vertex $w$ which is covered by some edge $e \in M$ and hence $(M \setminus \{e\}) \cup \{vw\}$ is maximal matching as well, so in connected graphs the answer is positive.

Comment: What you just described, is not unique!
(a)---------(b)---------(c)

then there are TWO maximum matchings, (a,b) AND (b,c)
they are both maximum, since their size is 1 edge

UNIQUE means that we cannot find another maximum matching with the same size

Comment: No, you misread my definition since the graph you drew has two edges rather than one.

Comment: okay, I forgot to include one important KEY word in my question, thanks for pointing it out, I meant CONNECTED graphs. I will update my question.

Comment: I edited my answer with a proof for the connected case. Also, please stop SCREAMING, it actively detracts from the readability of your posts.

Comment: it's to highlight key points, if you highlighted the point that it has one edge in your comment, I wouldn't have missed it I'm sure.

Comment: And thanks so much for the answer, I am new to the field, so, need to get used to making my own formal proofs! Your answer has provided me an important lesson.

Comment: There are _other_ **ways** to highlight things in text without making typographers sad, but these (in my opinion anyways) are to be used sparsely rather than three times per sentence (as, you know, if everything is highlighted then nothing is).